# How to show all unsaved files opened in vim?

Tags: save, linux, crash-recovery

I'm not sure if I should ask this problem on vim or on Linux/Ubuntu forum.

The thing is, I opened multiple terminals on my desktop, and several of them opened various of `*.txt` files. Not all of them are saved.

Then my desktop partially broke down. I can ssh it from my laptop. Is there any way to know which files are opened in vim? And is there any way I can save the unsaved files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can modify those files, it's likely that Vim created swap files for them. Swap files have extensions `.swp`, `.swo`, ..., etc. You can search for these files using `find`. Looking in your home directory, for example:

```
find ~ -type f -name '.*.sw?'
```

If the Vim programs are still running, you could expedite the search by looking at which files are opened by the Vim processes. This can be done by examining the process' `/proc` entry and finding where the `fd`s point to (`ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd/`).

For example:

```
$ pgrep vim | xargs -i ls /proc/{}/fd -l
total 0
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Sep 25 08:31 0 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Sep 25 08:31 1 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Sep 25 08:31 2 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Sep 25 08:31 3 -> socket:[23224440]
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Sep 25 08:31 5 -> socket:[23220671]
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Sep 25 08:31 7 -> /tmp/.gameoverlayui.log.swp
total 0
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Sep 25 08:31 0 -> /dev/pts/5
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Sep 25 08:31 1 -> /dev/pts/5
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Sep 25 08:31 2 -> /dev/pts/5
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Sep 25 08:31 3 -> socket:[23222572]
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Sep 25 08:31 5 -> socket:[23223590]
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Sep 25 08:31 7 -> /home/muru/.vimhelp.vim.swp
```

So, I have two Vim windows, each having one file opened.

---

I don't think you can control those processes, not easily<sup>1</sup>, anyway. You *can* kill them, and then open those files again. Vim will detect the swap files and offer to recover:

```
$ pkill vim
$ vim /tmp/gameoverlayui.log
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name ".gameoverlayui.log.swp"
          owned by: muru   dated: Fri Sep 25 08:37:49 2015
         file name: /tmp/gameoverlayui.log
          modified: YES
         user name: muru   host name: muru-laptop
        process ID: 11066
While opening file "gameoverlayui.log"
             dated: Fri Sep 25 08:37:43 2015

(1) Another program may be editing the same file.  If this is the case,
    be careful not to end up with two different instances of the same
    file when making changes.  Quit, or continue with caution.
(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
    If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r gameoverlayui.log"
    to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
    If you did this already, delete the swap file ".gameoverlayui.log.swp"
    to avoid this message.

Swap file ".gameoverlayui.log.swp" already exists!
[O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (D)elete it, (Q)uit, (A)bort:
```

---

<sup>1</sup> You could use reptyr or one of the other solutions described in [this Unix & Linux post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4034/70524) to reattach the Vim process to your SSH session. I have no idea how that will work.

Answer (score 9):

`:ls` shows the current buffers (opened files)

A `+` mark before file path shows that file is modified.

Check [`:h :ls`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Als) for more details

Comment: This is the answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what muru posted, here's a 'not easy' way to control the processes hanging out there:

create and chmod +x type.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse
import fcntl,termios

p = argparse.ArgumentParses()
p.add_argument('fname')
p.add_argument('test')
args = p.parse_args()
fd = open(args.fname,'w')
for c in args.text:
    fcntl.ioctl(fd,termios.TIOCSTI,c)
```

then from bash run:

```
sudo ./type.py /proc/[vim pid goes here]/fd/0 $'\x1b\x1b:wq\x0d'
```

note the preceding two ESCs `(\x1b)` to (hopefully) get back to normal mode, and the following return `(\x0d)` to execute the wq

or do them all at once:

```
for i in $(pgrep vim); do sudo ./type.py /proc/$i/fd/0 $'\x1b\x1b:wq\x0d'; done
```